# Нормально ли звучит предложение?

Tags: порядок-слов

Предложение: «У меня не было награды почти до заключительного дня Олимпиады». Смущает место слова «почти».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обособление оборота оборот зависит **от контекста:**

(1) *У меня не было награды **почти до заключительного дня ОлимпиАды**.*

(2) *У меня нЕ было награды, **почти до заключительного дня Олимпиады.***

**Пояснение**

1. Наречие ***почти*** входит в состав обстоятельственного оборота со значением времени, поэтому обособляется или не обособляется вместе с ним.
2. Обособление оборота **факультативно**. Если оборот **не обособляется**, то ударение естественным образом переходит на конец фразы. Это сообщение о том, что наград не было почти до конца Олимпиады. Оборот включен **в состав предложения.**
3. Если оборот **обособляется** (актуализация оборота), то основным сообщением является первая часть фразы (наград не было), а оборот **уточняет** время (не было почти до конца Олимпиады).
4. Более вероятным является **первый вариант.**

Answer (score 0):

"Почти" является наречием и образовано из слова "почесть". Фактически "почти" - это вроде "почти за факт что" (часто даже говорят "почти что", что, в принципе, уже не наречие скорее, а оборот). Поскольку наречия связываются со сказуемым, то, очевидно, что в данной ситуации сказуемым является глагол "быть", а точнее его форма "не было". Однако положение усугубляет тот факт, что "почти" в русском языке приобретает иногда черты прилагательного: "почти растение" или сочетается с прилагательным: "почти белое лицо". Поэтому, например, в предложении "У почти меня не было награды до заключительного для Олимпиады" читающим чётко улавливается сочетание "почти я". Предварительно перебрав все позиции "почти", рассматривать я буду только три выглядищих жизнеспособными варианта:

1. У меня почти не было награды до заключительного для Олимпиады
2. У меня не было награды почти до заключительного дня Олимпиады
3. У меня не было награды до почти заключительного дня Олимпиады

Первый варант воспринимается, кажется, так: "может быть у меня и была какая-то награда, но вот настоящая награда появилась именно в заключительный день Олимпиады".
Во втором варианте я применю такой приём: заменю "почти" на оборот "почти что": "У меня не было награды почти что до заключительного дня Олимпиады". В этом случае смысл очевиден: человек не имел награду до заключительного дня Олимпиады, но заимел её в последний день.
В третьем случае "почти", кажется, не превращается в прилагательное, ибо, хотя и можно представить себе "почти заключительный день", но в данном случае это - не то. Поэтому я применю тут точно такой же приём: "У меня не было награды до почти что заключительного для Олимпиады". С этой конструкцией смысл тоже становится сразу понятным, однако акцент делается на "заключительном дне": тут именно говорится что заключительный день был главным. В предыдущем же примере акцент делался на "до", что "до заключительного дня награды не было".
Поэтому кажется, что логически 2-ой и 3-ий варианты эквивалентны, однако 2-ой делает акцент на времени до последнего дня, а 3-ий делает акцент на том, что награда была получена именно в заключительный день, то есть это чисто эмоциональный окрас.